# Do cron jobs in Node.js affect performance or create problems like memory leakage?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, cron

I have a cron job which will be created after every request of booking ticket and that job will run after 15 minutes and check if the payment is done. If not, then it will make that ticket available for other users.

```
new CronJob('*/15 * * * *', function () {
    const that = this;
    co(function* () {
      try {
        const order = yield mongoose.model('Orders').findById(orderId);
        if (order.orderStatus === 'pending') {
          order.orderStatus = 'released';
          yield order.save();
          yield mongoose.model('Outing').findByIdAndUpdate(outing, {
            '$set': {
              'showFlag': true
            }
          });
          console.log(`Order:${orderId} has been cancelled due to session time out - ${new Date()}`);
        } else if (order.orderStatus === 'released') {
          console.log(`Order:${orderId} is cancelled due to Client's request`);
        } else if (order.orderStatus === 'reserved') {
          console.log(`Order:${orderId} is reserved`);
        }
        console.log('Job ended:', new Date());
        that.stop();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }, null, true);
};
```

So what's happening here is a new job is created for every request, 15 minutes later the job is executed and then the respective cron job is stopped!
So will this affect performance in any way?
If yes, then do I have any other way to run this process in background?

Comment: What is CronJob? Cron has nothing to do with Node. You're using some sort of Cron helper or a substitute. It's unknown what it is and how it affects your app.

Comment: Will the garbage collector free the cron after the stop method is called?

Comment: I cannot say anything about `stop` because you didn't explain what CronJob is.

Comment: Ok. CronJob is an object which we can create using a node module called cron.
After getting this object we can run tasks in the server's background after a particular interval of time

Comment: This depends on `cron` then. If you're concerned with possible problems with third-party package, consider checking open issues in its repo. As for job function contents, this isn't specific to Cron but to how JS works. If there's a garbage to collect, it will be collected.  From what I see, there's nothing that I would expect to cause memory leaks in this function. I cannot guarantee that there won't be memory leaks, that's what you need to test yourself.